# Using ParallelTable for assignment

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, mathematical-optimization, parallelization

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

s[B_] := NMinimize[B*x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]

Table[s1[B] = s[B], {B, {1, 3, 10, 7}}];

s1[3]

(*{-1.49476, {x -> 0.779079}}*)

s1[10]

(*{-0.64752, {x -> 0.452979}}*)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

s[B_] := NMinimize[B*x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]

ParallelTable[s1[B] = s[B], {B, {1, 3, 10, 7}}];

s1[3]

(*s1[3]*)

s1[10]

(*s1[10]*)
```

Why, when using ParallelTable, it is not possible to assign s1[B] to the s[B], but in the case of Table it is possible?

How should it be implemented?

Comment: It seems a definition distribution problem. I'd assume the `s1` definitions are made on the parallel kernels and not accessible to the main kernel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct answer to "how should it be implemented" is to use `SetSharedFunction`. Evaluate `SetSharedFunction[s1]` before the `ParallelTable`, and you'll get your expected results.

However, this whole approach seems very misguided. There seems to be no reason to use parallelization for this. Furthermore, `Table` itself is a strange choice to use for creating down values. So, I think the real answer to "how should it be implemented" is that you should take a completely different approach. We'd need more context to determine that approach, however.

Comment: Thanks! My real code has the same structure as this example. There is some function that is found by minimization and depends on the parameter (B). Aftrethat I use ParallelTebale for assignment

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply a function to every element of some list, there is "Map" or "ParallelMap".

For your example this wouldreadusing ParallelMap):

```
s[B_] := NMinimize[B*x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]
s1 = ParallelMap[s, {1, 3, 10, 7}]

{{-3.51391, {x -> 1.30084}}, {-1.49476, {x -> 
    0.779079}}, {-0.64752, {x -> 0.452979}}, {-0.82037, {x -> 
    0.530649}}}
```